# Using integral2 in Matlab with vectors

Tags: matlab

I am trying to **numerically** evaluate a double integral. The specific integral is too complicated, but it is not relevant here, I only want the main idea.

Suppose I have:

```
x=1;
y=1;

fun = @(theta,phi)  (x.*sin(theta) + y.*cos(phi));
result = integral2(fun,0,pi,0,2*pi)
```

This gives a single value. Assume I'd like to do this for a range of values for X and Y. 
Ideally, I'd like to have x,y as vectors:

```
x=1:10;
y=1:10;
```

Matlab gives (Error using  .* Matrix dimensions must agree.)

What is the solution? (Ideally, I do not want to use for loop).

Comment: Are you sure that you want to integrate over dtheta/dphi this way, without using  [this formula](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/6/9/7/6976a7e30290b168b947d416b9abe13e.png)? Just curious

Comment: I do not think I'll need that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `arrayfun` to "lift" your function when you want it to accept arrays

```
x = 1:10;
y = 1:10;
result = arrayfun(@(x, y) integral2(@(theta,phi) x.*sin(theta) + y.*cos(phi),0,pi,0,2*pi), x, y);
```

or

```
fun = @(theta, phi, x, y) x.*sin(theta) + y.*cos(phi);
result = arrayfun(@(x, y) integral2(@(theta,phi)fun(theta,phi,x,y), 0,pi,0,2*pi), x, y);
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, that did it!

BTW, is this the "standard" way to do it? or it is a "trick" ?

Comment: It is a standard way to make a one-liner. It is not a true vectorization so it may be slow (compare `x = ones(1, 1000000);tic;x = x * 2;toc` with `y = ones(1, 1000000);tic;y = arrayfun(@(y) y*2, y);toc`) but in cases like yours (small number of iterations, heavy iterations themselves) when you can't properly vectorize it helps without any problem

Comment: I see. BTW, what if I want to use an 'alias' like z=sin(theta)*cos(phi), where z is just a shortcut to simplify the typing. I cannot define it as a variable since theta itself is not defined as proper variable. Any ideas?

Comment: You can define a function `z=@(theta, phi) sin(theta)*cos(phi)` and use it as `z(theta, phi)`

Comment: So no method will allow me to write only z? Because I am writing that tens of times and would like it to be short.

Comment: No, you'll also need to write variables to substitute in the brackets